# Scrollbar render misplaced in QTwebkit Qwebview

Tags: qt, webkit, qt5, qtwebkit, qwebview

I have a weird scrollbar bug using Qwebview in Qt5.
the scrollbars appears on the opposite side, while the action is still performed on the right side. For example, the rightside scrollbar can me moved from the right, but visually the bar moves on the left as you can see in this image:

[image]

Any idea what can be the cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, got it actually this is a CSS issue

I had this:

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

applied on the body. This is the cause to the problem. Don't know exactly why, but this attribute duplicates/mirrors all scrollbars in webkit on QT